# "load_breast_cancer" could not be loaded for iPython notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I tried to run `from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer` on my iPython notebook (Python 2, Jupyter, Dato), and got the importError:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-09d44d891711> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

ImportError: cannot import name load_breast_cancer
```

But it works fine if I run others, e.g. `from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes`, `from sklearn.datasets import load_boston`.

So how to import the `load_breast_cancer`? Thank you.

Comment: It works fine for me `In [3]: from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer` returns with no problem. What version of sklearn are you using. Can you try installing the latest version through pip ?

Comment: should I use "pip install -U scikit-learn"? where should I type this?

Comment: in a terminal window

Comment: I tried this on my windows cmd command, the installation is fine. But the load_breast_cancer is still not working

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install --upgrade sklearn`

if you don't know where your kernel is running (if updating your machine didn't work, it seems like it is hosted somewhere else), run  `!pip install --upgrade sklearn` in a notebook cell.

Comment: I tried this on my windows cmd command, the installation is fine. But the load_breast_cancer is still not working

Comment: how do I know which version?

Comment: if I install the sklearn on cmd, could it still be used by iPython notebook? I feel they are two separate things

Comment: import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)   0.16.1   this is for my ipython notebook

Comment: did you restart the kernel and reimport after installing? where is the kernel running?

Comment: yes, I restarted. The ipython notebook is run in Chrome

Comment: no, it is *viewed* in chrome. where is the *kernel* running. the backend server that runs the actual python

Comment: how do I know "where is the kernel running"?

Comment: I re-installed my "GraphLab Create", and it works now!